# How to map dlsym to a non-static C++ member function in a manner similar to a C function?

Tags: c++, linux, g++, dlsym

I studied and tested the following URLS closely, [Calling function in shared library (Linux) get Segmentation Fault](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26638269/calling-function-in-shared-library)
as well as https://git.xeserv.us/Quora/dlsym-example/src/master/testprog.c.
  My question is how to map dlsym to a non-static C++ member function similar to this C function example. If I substitute C function syntax for a non-static C++ member function , I get a no-op.

```
   void *lib;              /* void pointer named lib */
   void (*sayHello)(void); /* void pointer named sayHello */
   lib = dlopen("helloWorld.so", RTLD_NOW);

   *(void **) (&sayHello) = dlsym(lib,"_ZN19CDataTransferServer10InitializeEi13CC_SAMPLETYPEjjj");
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: C++ has no ABI (Application Binary Interface) and linkage  is compiler (even compiler version) dependent.

Comment: @Basilev, The compiler tag is g++ (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04) 4.8.4.

Comment: @Dieter Lücking, Is C++ name mangling relevant to this purpose or not?

Comment: @richpe, mangling is absolutely relevant. Please edit your post to include your failed C++ attempt, instead of irrelevant C one.

Comment: Related: [Wrong arguments position in function imported with dlsym](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16820055)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is Linux utility to mangle a C++ symbol name?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11335624/what-is-linux-utility-to-mangle-a-c-symbol-name)

Comment: @richpe your latest edit intrduces obviously incorrect cast of function pointer. I can derive from mangled name of function you use, that it accepts arguments (at least two) and you are trying to assign it to a pointer to function that accepts no arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider loading a method by its mangled name extracted with

```
readelf -Ws libmy.so
```

or

```
nm -g libmy.o
```

Comment: Thank you for the great answer. Do I need to include any header files which resolve the mangled names such as:_ZN19CDataTransferServer10InitializeEi13CC_SAMPLETYPEjjj?

Comment: You will need a definition of DataTransferServer to have a typed pointer to its method.

Comment: I just included DataServer.h and compiled with g++ -g -DLINUX -I /home/vend/developmentMono/SmartCamXi_Hybrid/Include test.cpp -ldl and got the following compiler errors:
  test.cpp:33:48: error: ‘_ZN19CDataTransferServer10InitializeEi13CC_SAMPLETYPEjjj’ was not declared in this scope
   *(bool **)(&sayHello) = (bool *)dlsym(handle,_ZN19CDataTransferServer10InitializeEi13CC_SAMPLETYPEjjj);
Please suggest a way to workaround these errors. Thanks.

Comment: I was just informed you cannot access a c++ class by using dlopen and dlsym since they are C functions. Instead a better way is described in this URL, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/496664/c-dynamic-shared-library-on-linux. Thank you for all of your help.

Comment: You should provide a string literal, not a symbol as argument of dlsym. every C++ method is a C function with a mangled name (at least in GCC world).